# Let f be a function from $A$ to $B$. Let $S$ be a subset of $B$. Show that $f^{−1}( \overline{ S}) =(\overline{f^{−1}(S)}) $.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

As you saw in the question, assume $S \subseteq B$, show that $f^{−1}( \overline{ S}) =(\overline{f^{−1}(S)})$.

I just need to show the first part $f^{−1}( \overline{ S}) \subseteq (\overline{f^{−1}(S)})$.  without proving the other part $ (\overline{f^{−1}(S)}) \subseteq f^{−1}( \overline{ S}) $ to prove they are equal.

Proof:

To prove the first part $f^{−1}( \overline{ S}) \subseteq (\overline{f^{−1}(S)})$, we will let $x \in f^{-1}(\overline{S})$ and show in a sequence of steps that  $x \in \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$ based on my understanding eventually. Then $ \exists y \in \overline{S} $ such that $f(x)=y$.

The proof proceeded then by saying that, based on the definition of the complement, $ \exists y \in \overline{S} $ is equivalent to,

$$ \neg (y\in S)$$

Since $f(x) = y$, then,
$$ \neg (f(x)\in S)$$

Up to now, the proof makes sense, but I don't understand the following steps that lead to the final conclusion:

1. $f^{-1}(S)$ contains all elements whose image is in $S$, $$ \neg
       (f(x)\in S)$$, then
   $$\neg(x \in f^{-1}(S))$$
2. By the definition of the complement,

$$x\in \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$$

By the definition of the subset,

$$f^{−1}( \overline{ S})\subseteq (\overline{f^{−1}(S)})$$

Can you please clarify point 1 above as I don't get how it was brought above in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in f^{-1}(\overline{S})$ then by definition $f(x)\in \overline{S}$ it is
$f(x)\not \in S$ then$f(x) \not \in f^{-1}(S)$ and therefore
$f(x)\in \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$  therefore $x\in \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$.

And $f^{-1}(\overline{S}) \subset \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$ holds.

Now let $y\in \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$ then $f(y)\not \in S$ and therefore
$f(y)\in f^{-1}(\overline{S})$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(\overline{S}) \supset \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$.

And then $f^{-1}(\overline{S}) = \overline{f^{-1}(S)}$ .

Answer (score 2):

By stating the definition of preimmage
$$f^{-1}(S) = \{ x\in A : f(x)\in S \} ,$$
so, by definition, if $f(x) \not \in S \Longrightarrow x\not \in f^{-1}(S)$.

Comment: So,  $\neg (f(x)\in S)$ was swapped with $\neg(x \in f^{-1}(S))$ based on the definition or he added $\neg(x \in f^{-1}(S))$ based on the definition?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: So,  $\neg (f(x)\in S)$ was replaced with $\neg(x \in f^{-1}(S))$ based on the definition of the preimmage or he added $\neg(x \in f^{-1}(S))$ after based $\neg (f(x)\in S)$ in the proof based on the definition of the preimmage ?